# How to show top 10 values only in grafana

Tags: grafana

I am using grafana to display certain metrics. Sometimes the list is so big that I would need only top 10 values to be displayed. What is the option that Grafana provides for the same. I am using "Graph" panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not an option in Grafana as you would do this with the query language of the time series database that you are using.

- Graphite has the [limit](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.limit) function.
- InfluxDB has the [limit and slimit](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/data_exploration/#the-limit-and-slimit-clauses) functions
- ElasticSearch has the Size option:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you use prometheus you could do this:
https://www.robustperception.io/graph-top-n-time-series-in-grafana